# Can I choose "Artifact Creature" as a creature type as Adaptive Automaton enters the battlefield?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

I want to use the card [Adaptive Automaton](http://gatherer.wizards.com/pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=220147) in my white artifacts deck. Most of the creatures in the deck are artifact creatures. Now, I am not sure if "artifact creature" is a correct creature type. Let's take [Palladium Myr](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=212251) for example. It is of creature type "Myr" and also an "artifact creature". Are both attributes real creature types?

In case I cannot choose "artifact creature", those automatons will find a new home in my Elves deck, but I would prefer to have them in my white artifacts deck.

Comment: You may be interested in [Xenograft](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=227544)

Comment: Or even more so: [Steel Overseer](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=205036) and [Tempered Steel](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=194391).

Comment: ghoppe: Interesting... I don't have blue in the deck in question but it might be interesting for other decks.


adamjford: I have 4 Tempered Steel in my Deck, they are really key to winning. I also experimented with Steel Overseers, but they are usually too slow to really pay off in my deck.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

No, you can't, because "artifact" is not a *creature type*, it's a *card type*.

The information on the type line is divided into two portions, the type(s) and the subtype(s). Each word before the dash represents a type of the card, and each word after the dash (if any) represents a subtype. For example, Palladium Myr's type line says "Artifact Creature - Myr" so "artifact" and "creature" are its types and "Myr" is its subtype.

When a card says "creature type," it effectively means "subtype of a card which has 'Creature' or 'Tribal' as a type." In other words, the creature type is always a subtype, something that must appear *after* the dash.

Also, the complete list of possible creature types is given in the [comprehensive rules](http://www.wizards.com/Magic/TCG/Article.aspx?x=magic/rules), rule 204.3k as of this writing. When a card like Adaptive Automaton asks you to choose a creature type, you're only allowed to choose one of the words from that list (according to rule 204.3d).

Answer (score 4):

"Artifact creature" is a *card type* (2 types to be exact, Artifact, and Creature), not a *creature type*. A *creature type* is always a sub-type of the "Creature" card type, like Elf, Orc, HUman, Soldier, Myr, and so on. So since Adaptive Automaton requires you to pick a *creature type*, you cannot pick "Artifact Creature"